# Phantom js битый скриншот

Tags: phantomjs

Здравствуйте!
Потребовалось делать в скриншоты сайтов на пхп.
Установил на Ubuntu phantomjs.

Написал скрипт:

```
system = require('system');
var url = system.args[1];
var filename = system.args[2];
var WebPage = require('webpage');
page = WebPage.create();
page.open(url);
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
page.render(filename + '.png');
phantom.exit();
}
```

Вызываю скрипт:

```
phantomjs phantomsave.js https://www.yandex.ru 331
```

Всё сохраняет корректно.
Вызываю для другого сайта:

```
phantomjs phantomsave.js https://www.google.ru 331
```

Создаётся картинка весом 1 кб. Пустая. И главное для нужного сайта то же самое. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема из за https сайтов. Http - корректно.

Comment: Оказывается для рендеринга сайтов https нужно вызывать скрипт с поддержкой ssl пример: phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any phantomsave.js google.ru 331 . НО теперь другая проблема. Половина содержимого на странице нет. Только границы блоков без текста и картинок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По результатам множественных экспериментов:
wkhtmltoimage работает в разы корректнее. Bin в bin chmod +x и вызов.

```
wkhtmltoimage --crop-h обрезка_по_высоте --javascript-delay время_ожидания_загрузки_ява_скрипт адрес_сайта имя_файла
```

[wkhtmltoimage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)